# Why my style isn't working as expected?

Tags: html, css

I made a simple style with my simple page but it doesn't work and I have no idea why.
The button has one color, and the color doesn't change even if I click on it.
Here's the source code: (index.html, no more files needed)

```
<html>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="cs">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   <body>
    <style>
     a:link {color: blue; font-family: Arial, Sans Serif; text-decoration: underline;}
     a:hover {color:    red; font-family: Arial, Sans Serif; text-decoration: underline;}
     a:active {color: green; font-family: Arial, Sans Serif; text-decoration: underline;}
     a:visited {color: navy; font-family: Arial, Sans Serif; text-decoration: underline;}
    </style>
<a href="">Hello world!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's link to the page, so you can see.](http://mojeobrazovka.xf.cz)
EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add the  tag.

Comment: Is your `<style>` declaration really inside the `<body>` or is it in the `<head>`?

Comment: Completely invalid markup. No `<head>` section. Your `<style>` block should be in your `<head>`. No closing `</html>`. You should review some basic fundamentals before continuing...

Comment: @War10ck Well, the closing html tag WAS there, but for some reason it didn't show up in the Stackoverflow's code viewer (or how should I call it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when multiple selectors apply to the same element, the one that has the greatest "weight" (the proper technical term is *specificity*) wins over the others. In case of a tie, the selector that appears last wins.

In this case all of the selectors have the same specificity and `a:visited` appears last, therefore your link will appear to be:

- blue, if you have never visited it and don't interact with it
- red, if you have never visited it but you are hovering it
- green, if you have never visited it but have the mouse button down
- navy if you have visited it even once, *regardless of anything else*

Comment: It works if they are reordered to: link, visited, hover, active.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Exactly.